# Is there a word for a gel turning into liquid?

Tags: word-request

We have a word called evaporation for liquid turning into vapour. Is there a word for something turning from gel to liquid?

The thing is that I have a plant "Aloe Vera" and it has a gel substance in it. But if you pluck it and let it rest for few days, the gel turns into liquid.

Is there a word for it?

Comment: **Deliquesce**: (Of organic matter) become liquid, typically during decomposition.

Comment: Is there a precipitate formed, or does all of the gel seem to have turned into a liquid?

Comment: @JoeDark I don't think that's a good choice, for two reasons. First, it's usually used with the meaning it has in chemistry, which is to absorb moisture from the air, and that's not what's happening here. Second, outside chemistry, it's a very rare word so it's not likely to be understood. Anyone who's familiar with the meaning from chemistry will misunderstand you; anyone who isn't, probably just won't understand.

Comment: @JoeDark, David, Thirdly, not all gels are organic, so it's wrong on a technical level anyway. (Nice word of the day for me though!)

Comment: @JamesWebster Sure, though I don't think it's a technical word, in that sense. Even if it is, using technical terms figuratively in a non-technical sense is fairly common.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M all the gel.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The general technical term for a solid or gas becoming a liquid is "**liquefaction**" (the verb form of which is **liquefy**) - but it's something that I'd say is probably mainly used in engineering/materials science contexts for this.

Since a gel is classed as a solid (technically, a solid with liquid dispersed through it), I'd say it's fine to refer to its liquefaction (certainly in any casual context) as "**melting**", same as you would any other solid.

Comment: It is indeed liquefaction. The best speculation I came up so far is [Gelatin Liquefaction By Bacteria](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC379018/pdf/jbacter01057-0015.pdf), which agrees.

Answer (score 9):

There are two answers suggesting *melt.*  This is not a bad choice, and in many circumstances it is the one I would use.  It would be widely understood and wouldn't raise many eyebrows.

That said, *melt* carries at least a little hint of a sense of temperature changes.  (I think butter *melts* because the colloidal fats actually do change from solid to liquid with temperature changes.)

@JezW mentioned the noun *liquefaction.*  I agree that in the noun form it is technical jargon rarely heard outside of science/engineering.  I believe the conjugated verb form, *liquefy/liquefied,* is used more widely. (var spelling: *liquify*)

If the gel turns to a liquid completely in the absence of temperature changes, I would use *liquefy.*

> If you squeeze a corn-starch and water mixture it will harden in your hand, but if you relax your grip it will liquefy again.
>
> I left a jar of mayonnaise in the fridge for a year.  When I opened it, it had completely *liquefied.*  Do you think it is safe to eat?
>
> If you don't use your hand sanitizer within a month or two, it might start to liquefy.

In the later two cases the implication is that despite stable temperatures, something else has caused the structure to *break down*  - the solids spread through the liquid are settling, or are simply falling apart.

Evidence for this word being used outside of a scientific context:
The song "Liquefy,"  by the band The Servant: [youtube link to music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAtlBM9iK_U)

---

TLDR;  I would consider *liquefy/liquefaction* to be the general term.  It could occur due to *melting, decay, decomposition, sedimentation, deliquescence, etc.*  In casual circumstances, people might use *melt* for any of these, but it has connotations of temperature change, and will sound strange if people *know* one of the other mechanisms to be at work.  *Liquefy* is widely understood, and always means *turns into a liquid,* whether by chemical, thermal or mechanical processes.

Comment: Huh  -  _Sublimate_ used to be more widely used : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=liquefy%2Csolidify%2Cliquify%2Csublimate%2C+evaporate&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cliquefy%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bliquefy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLiquefy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csolidify%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cliquify%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bliquify%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLiquify%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csublimate%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsublimate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSublimate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cevaporate%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bevaporate%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEvaporate%3B%2Cc0common

Comment: Liquefy it is; they have to expect correction from the nitpicky me if they say *melt*. :)

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M - Do you know why _Sublimate_ might have been so much more popular mid-century?  Was there some field of research into sublimation that was just opening up?

Comment: @Adam It peaks at the beginning of the 20th century, not the middle; and most of those hits are medical uses of "corrosive sublimate", an old name for mercury bichloride, used as a topical antiseptic.

Answer (score 5):

To deliquesce is to absorb moisture from the air.  That is not what your aloe is doing.  The gel is a colloid of protein and water.  The protein chains
are breaking down.  I would call that 'decay'.
  Thixotropic colloids become more slippery under shear, because the chains get aligned when they are dragged past each other.  That is what happens
when you pinch the fresh aloe.

Comment: It seems bacteria are responsible for the *decomposition* of the polypeptide chains. I believe the part "sol->liquid" is indeed "liquefaction", however *decomposition* (not "decay") is spot on and more scientific. (Note that everyday life usually doesn't refer to what happens 'behind the scenes', rather what is observed)

Answer (score 4):

There are common<sup>1</sup> words for all the transitions between the common states of matter:

```
Solid  -> Liquid   = Melt
Solid  -> Gas      = Sublimate
Liquid -> Gas      = Evaporate / Boil
Liquid -> Solid    = Solidify / Freeze
Gas    -> Solid    = Desublimate / Sublimate [2]
Gas    -> Liquid   = Condense
```

The problem is that gel is a **colloid**. That is, it has two parts, in two states, one spread throughout the other. In this case, there is a solid spread throughout a liquid.

Since the same is true of butter, (solid fat spread through water), and butter **melts**, I'd be happy to use the word **melt** for a gel too.

---

<sup>1. Ok, sublimate isn't exactly common, and this list isn't complete, just provides some options.</sup>

<sup>2. See comments.</sup>

Comment: Gas --> Solid is also (perhaps more commonly?) referred to as _deposition._  And _freezing_ is a decent synonym for _solidifying._

Comment: @Adam, huh, I've never heard of deposition in that context. I only know the "ousting" and legal contexts. Can't believe I forgot about freezing :P

Comment: "Thaw" is a synonym for "melt", but it assumes that the starting substance is frozen hard (like ice cream, not tepid butter).  "Freeze" is a synonym for "solidify".

Comment: @James Webster -- "[Chemical Vapor Deposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_vapor_deposition)" (CVD) is one of the choices a manufacturer has for applying a coating to a material.  Sometimes the "coating" is the entire material, which is then removed from the substrate it was deposited on.  You probably use some products that were made (or coated) by CVD on a daily basis.

Comment: @Jasper, Well I've learned something new!

Comment: Deposition is common; however, *sublimate* is indeed common in a theoretical chemistry context. If a colloid *relaxes* though, we'll call the process "sedimentation".

Comment: "Thaw" and "melt" are not synonyms at all. After thawing, an object (usually food or plants) is typically still solid, though the ice in it has melted

Comment: @Adam "Deposition" isn't *quite* the same thing as 'sublimation'. 'Deposition' is aerosol particles (liquid droplets or small solids) falling out of suspension in the air, whereas 'sublimation' is the gas itself becoming a solid (e.g. carbon dioxide, which under atmospheric pressure doesn't condense into a liquid but directly becomes solid - 'dry ice' - when cooled)

Comment: @JezW, it seems there are two meanings in chemistry: `In chemistry, deposition occurs when molecules settle out of a solution` and `Deposition (phase transition)

Water vapor from humid winter-air deposits directly into a solid, crystalline frost pattern on a window, without ever being liquid in the process.
Deposition, also known as desublimation, is a thermodynamic process, a phase transition in which gas transforms into solid. The reverse of deposition is sublimation.`

Comment: @James H-uh. Nevermind then - for some reason I remember 'sublimation' in chemistry lessons being referred to as both directions in that process, though admittedly it's a while ago... My mistake.

Comment: @JezW, that's what I remember too. I didn't even know the word `deposition` (in a chemistry context) before yesterday

Answer (score 1):

[Thixotropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thixotropy) is defined to be the gel -> fluid behavior you describe.

Another answer mentioned it but settled on a different word.

Comment: Thixotrophy is used for a gel that temporarily turns to liquid when subjected to shear stress, then reverts back to a gel when left alone.  That may not be what the O.P. is looking for.

Comment: What is the verb form of "thixotropy"?